# How do you screw in double-ended screws?

Tags: screws, furniture

I have a flat pack shelving unit to put together. It has double ended screws. According to the instructions you just screw them in using your hands. This is impossible: the pre-drilled holes seem way too small for the screws. I am unable to screw a nut on to tighten with a spanner as it is two normal screws stuck together not the usual version.

Suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 9):

Since the double ended screws are typically for attaching two wood surfaces together, start the screw in one of the pilot holes (just enough to stay put). Then align the other pilot hole and spin one or both pieces of wood together.

For example, if this is the below end cap on a wood pole, you'd put the screw on the end of the pole so that it doesn't fall and then spin the cap on until the screw is embedded in both surfaces and they are tight together. The only time you need to use pliers on the center piece is if you need to remove the screw.

[image: double ended screw on end cap]

Answer (score 6):

Does the screw look something like this:

[image]

You can see that there is a piece in the middle that doesn't have a thread and is faceted rather than round.

You should be able to use a small spanner or pair of pincers to screw it into the first piece.

The other solution is to make the pilot hole *slightly* larger so you can screw it in with your hands.

Comment: Or if you're attaching something like a table leg, get the screw started in one piece of wood, and spin the adjoining piece of wood until the screw pulls both pieces tight. No need to wear out your hands.

Comment: @BMitch - that's worthy of a different answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I was trying to be lazy, and your answer has a good picture in it. :)

Comment: YES it works (above posting) - drill a little hole to get you started and put screw between wood poles and turn them by hand at the same time , really easy, and I'm a woman :O) GREAT THANKS

Answer (score 4):

Double ended screws are only used where you can spin the two pieces together. Don't screw in one and, then the other. There is no need for a wrench in the middle. This will usually only bung up the threads.

Start the screws in both holes at once, just as far as your fingers will start them. (That won't be far, nor does it need be.) Just turn the pieces. Both ends of the screw will feed in at once. This works because if one of them gets too deep, it will have more friction, allowing the other end to catch up.

Answer (score 3):

Chuck the dowel screw into a drill.  Yes, you will bung up some threads, but not so badly that it won't work just fine.  After you do the first end, then that piece will be your handle for the other.

Answer (score 1):

Rockler (and Amazon) sell drivers for dowel screws. [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004SMFFCE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004SMFFCE)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange  If you are answering a question then please be descriptive in your explanation of how to do what  it is you are advising to do. A useful answer will have  a detailed explanation of the advise you are giving, NOT just a one line statement and a link.   **Please take the tour** so you know how to participate here. - https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour